# angular schema json array of object

Tags: json, angular, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to create an array of object but I can not do it anyone can help me please
how I can declare it in the schema?

**I want my array to be like this**

**favorite=[ {name:"shoes", rating:0} ];**

I would be happy to help :)

this is my user schema

```
import { Document, Schema, model } from "mongoose";
export interface IUserModel extends Document {
    favorite:Array<any>; //Maybe I should change that too
}
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUserModel>({
favorite:{
        type: Array,
        items:{
            type: String
        } // here is the problem how to declare array of object?
});

export const UserModel = model<IUserModel>("UserModel", UserSchema, "Users");
```

Comment: There is no such thing: `[name: "shoes", rating: 0]`, there is `{name: "shoes", rating: 0}` or `[{name: "shoes"}, {rating: 0}]`

Comment: @nimrodserok like something like this I want to do 
[ {name:"shoes", rating:0} ];
But I do not know how to set it schema

Comment: Will it be  `[ {name:"shoes", rating:0}, {name:"shirts", rating:3}  ]`? Will all objects have the same keys? Do you want to define the keys in the schema?

Comment: @nimrodserok What I want to do is that each user schema has an array and then I want to access this array to check which name has the highest rating

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
first, you can create a model class with the name Item

```
export class Item {
  name: null;
  rating: 0;
}
```

Now you can use it like this as an Array.

```
 favorite = [new Item()];
```